# Why doesn't my PDF have updates made to the original EPUB?

Tags: epub, calibre, pdf, conversion

In Calibre, I went in the editor and edited an EPUB and everything is fine; even sent the updated book to my Kindle and the updates are there. When I convert to PDF in Calibre and save to disk the changes aren't reflected. I even go find the file on disk and remove it to re-create it. I've also extracted the EPUB to a zip and checked the files, and the updates are there. The last thing I tried is supplying a folder to debug while converting to PDF and the files in the first folders (input, parsed, structure) are correct, but the last folder (processed) still doesn't have my updates.

I thought maybe the PDF is cached by my browser, but I turned that off and the problem remains, and wouldn't explain why the old code is still showing up in the `processed` debug folder.

Is there some cache somewhere? This isn't making sense.

Comment: So this is an Epub file that was uploaded thru Kindle Create/Previewer (where it appears visually fine in previewer tool) then after export to the final KDP PDF state its not? 

One random possible factor....did your epub changes get dropped into another sub-directory inside the epub? 
OEBPS/dir/stashed-here-by-accident. 
Whereas your changes should have been placed here: 
OEBPS/text/here-is-old-code-still-needing-overwritten. 

Also...did you use EpubCheck tool? Run it through that before uploading to Kindle Create/Previewer to reveal easily overlooked errors.

Comment: @granite I uploaded it to my Kindle device and it has my changes. For changes in EPUB, I can see that there's a file that's changed, no new files were created. I'll check out that tool, I've never used that or Kindle Create/Preview

Comment: This "calibre help" page might be offer a solution: 
https://manual.calibre-ebook.com/conversion.html  

Perhaps the Pandoc tool (converts ePub to PDF). 
https://pandoc.org/try/